# Adding two numbers together, get 5+10 = 510 instead of 15

Tags: javascript, web, calculator

I just started learning JavaScript and I'm fiddling around with some code and I can't seem to find a way to really add two variables up and calculate their sum. I'm declaring 3 variables where I set one variable to the answer and the 2 others as the two numbers. So basically a, b, c where c = (a + b). However, whenever I try to run the code the result ends up in 'ab' instead of 'a + b' so if a = 5 and b = 10 it says '510' instead of '15'.

All the other symbols like '-' , '/' and '*' are working as intended, the only one that is not working is the '+'.

I figure the computer thinks I'm trying to print out the two strings but I want to add them up instead, just like you do when you alert something for example: `alert("Hello World" + a);`

Am I thinking in the right direction or is the problem something else? Here's the source code:

```
function addTwoNumbers(firstNumber,secondNumber,numberAdded){
    if(numberAdded == '+'){
        numberAdded = (firstNumber + secondNumber);
        alert("The summ of the two numbers is equal to: " + numberAdded);
    }
    else if(numberAdded == '-'){
        numberAdded = (firstNumber - secondNumber);
        alert("The difference of the two numbers is equal to: " + numberAdded);
    }
    else if(numberAdded == '/')
    {
        numberAdded = (firstNumber / secondNumber);
        alert("The 'kvot' of the two numbers is equal to: " + numberAdded);
    }
    else if(numberAdded == '*'){
        numberAdded = (firstNumber * secondNumber);
        alert("The product of the two numbers is equal to: " + numberAdded);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("I told you to use '+, -, / and *' not anything else!");
    }
}

var checker = true;

while(checker == true){
    alert("You will now be prompted to enter two numbers.");
    var firstNumber = prompt("Please enter the first number.");
    var secondNumber = prompt("Please enter the second number.");
    var numberAdded = prompt("Would you like to use '+, -, /, or * ?'");
    checker = false;

    addTwoNumbers(firstNumber, secondNumber, numberAdded);
    if(numberAdded != '+' && numberAdded != '-' && numberAdded != '/' && numberAdded != '*'){
        checker = true;
    }

    option = 0;

    while(option != 'y' && option != 'n'){
        var option = prompt("Would you like to make a calculation again? (y/n)");
        if(option == 'y'){
            checker = true;
        }
        else if(option == 'n'){
            checker = false;
        }
        else{
            alert("I said (y/n), try again...");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prompt` function return a string. So when you use the `+` operator on two string you are combining them together. Instead, parse the number strings to a number:

```
var firstNumber = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the first number."), 10);
var secondNumber = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the second number."), 10);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. That fixed it! It just feels so weird to not assign the variables to strings/int's/doubles etc. but I guess I'll get used to it eventually. May I ask what the 10's in those lines are doing?

Comment: Note that you can also use shorter syntax with unary `+` operator, i.e. `var firstNumber = +prompt("...", 10);`

Comment: its the radix value (decimal in this case). check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Ah, I get it know, once again. Thanks a lot :)